# Single photon, double slit question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, photons

If photons are fired conitnuosly one at a time through the double slits is the statistical outcome going through each slit 50%?

Comment: @JohnForkosh That a detector behind one of the slits destroy the intensity distribution does not draw the full picture. Even behind a single slit one will get fringes  (as well as behind any sharp edge). So a detector behind one slit or the close of  one slit will erase the fringes from this slit and for a detector could overshadow the fringes from the second slit, but it has to be underlined, that fringes still exist from single slit.

Comment: So, I love how the deeper one explores the more questions pop up (must be a quantum phenomenon).  So, this makes me think of "firing one photon at a time"  What is exactly being fired? How does one fire a superposition photon?  So, the observer who is collapsing the "wave function" by measuring it  is also the same observer  firing "a photon" that has no "a" to it?  The observer is observing and somehow isolating and "shooting"  a wave function/photon.  How is it possible to shoot "a"  (one) photon without it already being collapsed?  Getting complicated...

Answer (score 2):

The key feature of the double slit experiment is that the light passes through both slits at the same time. It does not go through one slit or the other but instead passes through both.

This happens because unlike macroscopic objects like baseballs quantum objects do not have a position. They are fuzzy objects that are spread out over a region of space. The double slit experiment only works when the photons are delocalised enough that their spatial extent covers both slits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You actually state it quite well: the statistical outcome, if you were to measure the path of the photon (or any other quantum particle, for all that matters), would be 50% for each slit. It would ruin the interference pattern on the screen, though.

The quantum description in absence of measurement would be to say that the statistical *amplitude* is the same for each slit.

Formally, the difference between both situation corresponds to the loss of coherences due to the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The information of the photon spreads outward everywhere. (The wave function evolves spreading out, so it goes through both slits, no 50/50 chance stuff here.) Once it interacts (wavefunction of photon becomes significantly non-zero at the surface/detector) with the surface/detector, the wave function evolves/collapses to one of its position eigenvalues.